# Замена переменной по принципу шаблонизатора

Tags: php

Добрый день. Не нашел ответа. Поэтому задам его сам.
Возможно ли преобразовать переменную в стиль шаблонизатора, если да, то приведите примером пожалуйста. Шаблонизаторы со стороны не интересуют.
Нужно, чтобы из `$name` стало `{name}`, а например из массива

```
$massiv = array('lala' => 'ляля', 'topolya' => 'тополя');
```

стало не

```
$massiv['lala']
```

а

```
{massiv['lala']}
```

или еще лучше

```
{massiv[lala]}
```

Вывод не такой:

`<?= 'Привет, '.$name.'!'; ?>`

А такой:

`Привет, {name}!`

Comment: Не понятна логика с массивами. `'lala'` и `'topolya'` - это значения, а ключи для них будут `0` и `1`, соответственно. И почему инициализация массива заменяется на его первое значение? А по поводу простой замены переменных - смотрите в сторону `preg_replace`

Comment: @fremail, сорян с массивами чет я уже тут навертел дел. Конечно же это значения, сейчас исправлю. А по поводу инициализации - просто пример, как должен выглядеть вывод значения массива с нужным ключом. Preg_replace насколько мне известно не позволяет исполнить задумку.

Comment: `<?=$massiv['lala']?>` , нет? Или `$object->{$massiv['lala']}->go();` ? Не понятно что хочешь в общем.

Comment: Естественно первое, при чем тут объект вообще? Только так: <?= {name} ?>Перечитай еще раз топик и если не поймешь, то еще раз и еще. На мой взгляд там все описано, что необходимо.

Comment: @Dmitry Potter здесь программисты а не прорицатели. Хочешь ответ - поясни корректно, что ты хочешь. Вот например  `Нужно, чтобы из $name стало {name}` - где стало, при выводе HTML на PHP? Или при вызове свойства объекта? Или в CRMине соседа Василия?) Подозреваю что первое - так и надо написать  `Хочу вывод переменных PHP в HTML сделать следущими способами {..способы..}  какими средствами кроме сторонних библиотек можно этого добиться?`

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр прошу прощения, был не прав. Так действительно правильнее. Предложи правку - я ее приму.

Comment: Если я правильно понял: есть некий текст, к примеру: `Привет, $name!`. Нужно этот текст преобразовать в `Привет, {name}`. Верно?

Comment: @fremail не совсем. На вашем же примере:
Есть: <?= 'Привет, '.$name.'!; ?>
Должно быть так: Привет, {name}!
В сторону шаблонизаторов нужно смотреть, но не пойму, где я могу это именно посмотреть. Хочу просто разобраться, как создается подобное.

Comment: Что-то я совсем запутался. Значит, у Вас есть некий PHP файл, а Вы из него хотите сделать шаблон, заменив вызов PHP переменных на `{переменная}` и убрав `<?` `?>`. Я просто не пойму, зачем? Но даже если так - Ваш скрипт должен открывать этот файл и парсить его как текст через тот же `preg_replace` или что-нибудь из этой оперы. Вот пример шаблонизатора Blade в Laravel: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/View/Compilers/BladeCompiler.php